# How do I set the src address dynamically?

Tags: javascript, src

I am trying to grab information from the page url to set the src for a data file.

So, say page url is: page.html?x=data_file_3
(The ideas is I could change the url to access other data files: data_file_4, etc.)

I grab the "data_file_3" part of the url and put it in a variable:
(the code I use for this works fine -- so result is)
folder = "/data_file_3/content.js" -- the content of this file is just an array

Then I try this:

```
<script id="url" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="javascript">
...
var u = document.getElementById('url');
u.src = folder;
...
</script>
```

But this doesn't work (the array data does not show up on the page). I put this code right where I used to hard code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/data_file_3/content.js"></script>
```

The hard-coded version works. Any ideas about how I can do this?

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you are trying to create script tags dynamically.

```
var scr = document.createElement('script');
    scr.src = 'script_path';

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scr);
```

You can wrap this in a function where 'script_path' is whatever you're path you're passing in.

Note also that 'text/javascript' is not required. All browsers understand that its javascript.

Comment: Makes perfect sense to me, but still isn't working (I used an alert() to check the path and it is correct). Is there some sort of "order of execution" thing here I am missing? If this appends to the head and the code using the data is in the body, why would that be an issue? I'm stumped.

Comment: [Here's the whole thing](view-source:http://mrthomasbh.squarespace.com/storage/interactive_reading.html) -- the src stuff is right in the head section. You can append ?z=/storage/crim/c02_irc_warrior to the url to see that the script does get the content folder.

Comment: You're using jQuery, so change your xcontent resource to be a json document and return it via an xhr request.